# MySQL - How to parse a string value to DATETIME format inside an Update statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an application which logs entries with datetime format. Now I want to push that datetime string into db. So i have the query

```
db.query "update processing set start_time = STR_TO_DATE('2017053008:04:45', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') where dated = '2017-06-07' and zone = 'W13';"
```

I have the datetime format in my log as "2017060708:04:45" and when I run the above query its inputs NULL in the filed start_time.

Any help in this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: i think you should add "/" to identify the month day  and year

Comment: Yes @EarvinNillCastillo it works with "/"; thanks.

Comment: Please  mark my comment as something useful if it helps you. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.query "update processing set start_time = STR_TO_DATE('2017053008:04:45', '%Y%m%d%H:%i:%s') where dated = '2017-06-07' and zone = 'W13';"
```

Try above query .

Hope this will helps.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar that works perfectly; sorry for not looking into mutiple options before posting here...

Answer (score 0):

try `STR_TO_DATE('2017053008:04:45', '%Y%m%d%H:%i:%s')` ， the next params must match with the first one,hope it works.